# How to hide toolbar from home screen?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am building an android application which requires login. I am using tool bar not the action bar and also have a navigation drawer installed with a bottom navigation. I successfully hid the the bottom navigation from the home screen but the menu from which settings is accessed from the tool bar are still their which may lead the user to access the app without logging in. I want to remove the the settings menu item from the home screen (login screen)
The Login Screen looks like this  [image]

MainActivity.KT:

```
package com.example.integratedmodulateoroperationroom

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.*
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.findNavController()

        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(R.id.homeFragment, R.id.loginFragment),
            drawer_layout
        )

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

        bottom_nav.setupWithNavController(navController)
        val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_nav)

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            bottomNavigationView.visibility = if(destination.id == R.id.loginFragment) {
                View.GONE
            } else {
                View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
        nav_view.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return item.onNavDestinationSelected(navController) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

activity_main.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_nav"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_nav_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment_login.XML (home screen):

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LoginFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.utils.widget.ImageFilterView
        android:id="@+id/login_logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/Username"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:hint="Login ID"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_logo">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/Password"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Username"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword">

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:text="Forgot Password?"
        android:textColor="@color/material_on_surface_emphasis_high_type"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Password" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_goToHomeScreen"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_design"
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:backgroundTint="@null"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The navigation controller which is used here lets us use `addOnDestinationChangedListener`. So using it here we can successfully remove toolbar from the home screen.

```
            toolbar.visibility = if (destination.id == R.id.loginFragment) {
                View.GONE
            } else {
                View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one `supportActionBar?.hide()` put it in onCreate method. Or you can check statement if user not entered set this to toolbat:`toolbar.visibility = View.GONE`

Comment: The solution you have posted removed the toolbar from all fragments. I do not know if I had done something wrong or not. Although I have found the solution which I will be posting below